# Get all last transactions and sum all and view in datagridview

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

I've searched for the solution for my issue but from what I've read, I am puzzled on how to incorporate it in my program.
I have one table. I just want to get all the last transactions of each Employees and sum all of them. Example:

```
|EmployeeID| |Date|             |Amount|
   101        5/5/2014            168.00
   102        5/5/2014            173.00
   101        5/10/2014           300.00
   102        5/11/2014           100.00
   103        5/11/2014           150.00
```

I need to get this value: `Total: 550.00`
My database is MS Access
This is my code:

```
SELECT SUM(SalesmanAcct) As total 
FROM (SELECT LAST(TransactionDate) FROM SalesmanLedger GROUP BY EmployeeID)
```

Comment: I was able to improve the code to this.... select employeeid, last(salesmanacct) from salesmanledger group by employeeid... with this, I am able to get the last transactions of each employee. what comes next is trying to figure out how to sum everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following query:-

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)
FROM TABLE1 WHERE in_DATE IN (SELECT to_DATE 
                              FROM (SELECT EmployeeID, MAX(in_Date) AS to_DATE
                                    FROM TABLE1
                                    GROUP BY EmployeeID) TAB1
                             )
```

Comment: It's adding everything even the previous TransactionDate of each Employee. I just need to add all last transactions of each Employee.

Comment: Thanks Ankit but it still doesnt do what its suppsed to do. Following your advice, I did this,.....   SELECT EmployeeID, TransactionDate, SUM(salemanacct)
FROM (SELECT EmployeeID, MAX(TransactionDate) AS ddate, salemanacct FROM SalesmanLedger GROUP BY EmployeeID) AS TAB
GROUP BY EmployeeID, TransactionDate  ----- If I run this on msaccess query design, it gives a prompt for parameters ->"Enter Parameter Value".

Comment: Thanks Ankit! It solved my problem. I'll just try to understand why it has to be queried like so because I need to do it to other columns as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `Amount`

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) As total 
FROM (SELECT LAST(Amount) FROM SalesmanLedger GROUP BY EmployeeID) as a
```

Comment: @Ibanez1408 . . . Not according to the sample data in your question.